Расчет процента значений из массива 1 содержащихся в массиве 2
У меня есть таблица со следующей структурой:



client_id
order_id
items_current_order
items_next_order




905562
4254677
{1, 2, 4}
{1}


905562
4254645
{1, 2, 5, 6}
{1,  6}



create table orders (
    client_id integer,
    order_id varchar(10),
    items_current_order varchar array, 
    items_next_order varchar array
  
);


INSERT INTO orders (client_id, order_id, items_current_order, items_next_order) 
VALUES (905562, '4254677', '{1, 2, 4}', '{1}'), 

(905562, '4254645', '{1, 2, 5, 6}', '{1,6}');

Мне нужно посчитать долю items из items_next_order содержащихся в items_current_order.
Так например для order_id = 4254645 доля должна быть 50%, так как только 2 айтема items_next_order из 4-х содержатся в items_current_order.
Пробовал посчитать количество (не долю) так:
SELECT
    client_id ,
    COUNT(1) AS count_values
FROM
    (SELECT
         client_id ,
         unnest(items_next_order) AS value
     FROM
         orders
     GROUP BY
         1, 2) AS a
WHERE
    value = ANY (SELECT unnest(items_current_order) FROM orders as rj WHERE rj.client_id = a.client_id )
GROUP BY
    client_id 



У меня есть таблица со следующей структурой Это вот ни разу не структура. Замените (или дополните) на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.
